# Install chromedriver via package instead of executable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I am working on a selenium webdriver project using python. My tests run only in chrome (when the executable file is present in the project). Is there an updated alternative to install the chromedriver via package?

My problem is that my code is in github, so if my colleague wants to test locally, the executable chromedriver file that works for me may not work for him. How can solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a great library to manage this: [webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

You can install ChromeDriver via **pip** with [chromedriver_installer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chromedriver_installer).

Comment: I'm trying to use it, but even so i'm not able to install chromedriver. See my tox.ini here http://take.ms/Lq37g and see my requirements.txt here http://take.ms/BZONn then after run `tox`, the chromedriver is not installed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

my way I install chromedriver

1. download the chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) locally

2)put it  in document in program files let said the path will be C:\Program Files \chromedriver

3)searching in windows for "environment variables"
[image]

4. press on environment variables

[image]

5)choosing in "system variables" ->"Path" and pressing Edit

[image]

6. pressing New and putting the path of the chromedriver
   [image]

pressing ok, and finish it

**to verify it work**
enter to cmd -> and writing "chromedriver"

[image]